# Изменение стилей html тегов

Tags: javascript, css

Возникла одна проблема, хочу изменить background одного div при нажатии на кнопку, но когда таким  образом обращаюсь к нему -

```
document.div.style.background = 'url(second_1.jpg) no-repeat';
```

то ничего не работает, в консоли пишется "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined". Вот весь код:

JS

```
function new_art() {
   document.div.style.background = 'url(second_1.jpg)';
}
```

CSS

```
div {
  background: url(first_1.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 15%;
  height: 87%;
}
div:hover {
  background: url(first_2.jpg);
}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<input type="button" value="Tap me!" onclick="new_art()">
```

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.background = 'url(second_1.jpg)' ;

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko большое спасибо, работает!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko подскажите пожалуйста, а как изменить hover в таком случае?

Comment: А что с ховер? У Вас же он работает.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko нужно было что бы и hover тоже другой был после нажатия кнопки, но я уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данная ошибка в буквальном переводе означает:

> "Чувак я не могу прочитать свойство `style` у **не существующего**
>   объекта"!!

В данном примире на лицо **не верное** обращение к Dom.
В js существует несколько способов обратиться к Dom большинство из них предпологают наличие у элемента уникального идентификатора (`id`) или `css` класса.
Вот некоторые из них:
Если элемент первый ребенок `body` можно обратиться так: `document.body.children[0]`.

`document.getElementById('id');` // поиск по id
`elem.getElementsByTagName(tag);` // ищет все элементы с заданным тегом tag внутри элемента elem и возвращает их в виде списка.
Вызов `elem.getElementsByClassName(className)` возвращает коллекцию элементов с классом className. Находит элемент и в том случае, если у него несколько классов, а искомый – один из них.
Вызов `elem.querySelectorAll(css)` возвращает все элементы внутри elem, удовлетворяющие CSS-селектору css.
Вызов `elem.querySelector(css`) возвращает не все, а только первый элемент, соответствующий CSS-селектору css.
Вот [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/document) можно почитать подробнее

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в строке:

```
document.body.div.style.background = 'url(second_1.jpg) no-repeat';
```

т.к. обращаться к элементу `div` 
через `document.body` не получится.

А что если у тебя будет 2 элемента div в body, то как понять к какому обращаться?

Поэтому если ты хочешь найти нужный тебе элемент, 
то используй:

```
document.getElementById('id элемента').style.background = 'url(second_1.jpg) no-repeat';
```